# break from while statement

Tags: arrays, while-loop, break, enter

how can i break from my while statement when i want to scanf numbers like 1 2 3 4 5 and then hit Enter and goes on with my code ... here is what i have done but nothing works

```
while(1){
    res=scanf("%d",&x);
        arr[i++]=x;
        counter++;
            if ( res == 0 ){
                printf("EOF\n");
                break;
            }
            if ( res != 1)
            {
                printf("Nespravny vstup.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            if ( counter > 100)
            {
                printf("Nespravny vstup.\n");
                return 1;
            }
    }
printf("Counter:%d\n", counter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `man` page of scanf:

```
NAME
   scanf,  fscanf, sscanf, vscanf, vsscanf, vfscanf 
...

RETURN VALUE
   These functions return the number of input items  successfully  matched
   and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the
   event of an early matching failure.

   The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before  either
   the  first  successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.  EOF is
   also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator
   for  the  stream  (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set indicate the
   error.
```

In your case, `scanf` will return 0 only in case of an *early matching failure*.

Comment: Yea but how to do it if user hit 1 2 3 and Enter and go on in code ?

Comment: To break, either type non-numeric characters (like `abcd` ) & Enter or just `Ctrl+D`

Answer (score 1):

return breaks off the whole function, try
    break;
instead of return.